# How to check array of data to where condition in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `book[]` input field that comes from the view

```
 $arr = $request->book_name;
 dd($arr);
```

the `dd` result is like

```
array:2 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "3"
]
```

I want to select data from the `library` table where `book_id` match whit the above array, I wrote the below query but it gives an error like:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
> Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type
> array, string  given, called in D

the query is like this:

```
$libQuantity = \DB::table('library')->select('quantity')->whereIn('book_id', '=', $arr)->get();
```

Comment: Is there a Library Model?

Comment: yes there is ``Library`` Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$libQuantity = \DB::table('library')
                    ->select('quantity')
                    ->whereIn('book_id', $arr)
                    ->get();
```

or

```
$libQuantity = \App\Models\Library::whereIn('book_id', $arr)
                    ->get(['library']);
```

The issue is

`'book_id', '=', $arr` should be `'book_id', $arr`

Comment: Hahah! I can't believe it was just because of ``=``, thank you bro it worked.